# how to ask qt create apk package for android without start a simulator

Tags: android, qt, android-emulator

The android simulator is very slow, I don't want to debug with a simulator. I just want the qt create the APK file, and copy it to real hardware, and test.

But seems there is NO option to let qt just create the APK file.

I use `qt5.1.0 in windows 7 64bit`

Can anyone there know how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

The android simulator is slow because most android device is arm architecture. You can use android sdk create a X86 avd(or use genymotion) and compile your qt project in X86 android mode. It will make test and run extremely fast.

Alternatively, you can build your project in command line (not in qt creator). Here is a [post](https://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2013/10/09/android-deployment-in-qt-5-2/) that will show you how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very fast alternative:

[genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/features/)

which you can launch from eclipse and android studio as well

Comment: The problem is how to create the apk file in qt, without any device simulator? There is a Publish command in menu Build, but after it starts, it says NO wizard.